# ELSE SELECT nothing/blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to have an 'ELSE' statement for every conditional statement in my stored procedures, how do I return make a procedure return nothing?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Account WHERE Account.username=@Username)
BEGIN
    SELECT Status 
    FROM   Account 
    WHERE Account.username=@Username
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT --nothing/blank
END
```

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the entire `ELSE` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but I have to put the unnecessary ELSEs, is it possible?

Comment: There is absolutely no need to have an `ELSE` matching each `IF`, it's an optional part. Just remove the whole block if you want to do nothing in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a variable:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Account WHERE Account.username=@Username)
BEGIN
    SELECT Status 
    FROM   Account 
    WHERE Account.username = @Username;
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    DECLARE @X int;
    SELECT @X = 0;
END;
```

Comment: This is the answer! Thanks a lot! I wish I could upvote this but I can't. But really, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Account WHERE Account.username=@Username)
BEGIN
    SELECT Status 
    FROM   Account 
    WHERE Account.username=@Username
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT "No rows found" as Status
END
```

Comment: :( but it has to return nothing at all

Comment: replace with null

Comment: NULL returns NULL, not nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Account WHERE Account.username=@Username)
BEGIN
    SELECT Status 
    FROM   Account 
    WHERE Account.username=@Username
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT NULL--nothing/blank
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Account WHERE Account.username=@Username)
BEGIN
    SELECT Status 
    FROM   Account 
    WHERE Account.username=@Username
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT NULL as 'Status'--nothing/blank
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the `Status` value or `NULL` if there is no matching row you can use a subquery:

```
select ( select Status from Account where username = @Username ) as Status;
```

The outer `select` will always return a result. If the subquery doesn't supply a value then the result will be NULL.

If you want different, i.e. non-NULL, default value you can use `Coalesce` and a subquery thusly:

```
select Coalesce(
  ( select Status from Account where username = @Username ), -- If found.
  0 -- Default value if not found.
  ) as Status;
```

**NB**: It is assumed that there is either a single matching row or no matching row. The code will fail if the subquery returns more than one value.

Note that by querying the table only once either solution avoids the possibility of a race condition with another session updating or deleting the row for a user between the `exists` check and the `select` that returns the `Status` value.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return nothing then no need to write else part.
It will shorten your code and easy to understand.

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Account WHERE Account.username=@Username)
BEGIN
    SELECT Status 
    FROM   Account 
    WHERE Account.username=@Username
END
Else part is required when you want to return something else above condition failed.

Comment: @nikita I know I could just disregard the ELSE but I had to pair the IFs with ELSEs as a coding rule..